# Facebook ads asynchronous jobs python

Tags: asynchronous, facebook-ads-api

Am using facebook ads python sdk and i'd like to retrieve all  active campaigns of an ad account and i got (#17) User request limit reached. I searched for async jobs to get the campaigns but i found that is only applied for getting insights.
I wonder how to retrieve campaigns with async jobs ?

Answer (score 1):

The Marketing API is rate limited to prevent an application using too many resources.

There is no way for you to asynchronously request campaigns, as async jobs are typically used when some computation needs to be performed before being able to return results. In the case of campaigns, no computation is needed.

To resolve this, you can try to:

- Request larger page sizes by using the `limit` parameter, this will result in fewer overall requests
- Space out the calls you are making so your overall rate is lower

More information about rate limits in the Marketing API can be found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting

Comment: Hi @paul-bain, so is it not a good idea to create ads using async method. But thier documentation on async says 
> "Use asynchronous requests to create ads and send numerous ads requests without having to block". Im asking this as i need to create a lot of ads, but was hitting rate limits. Thought async might help. Your opinion?